# If I have a Fragment with 3 possible layouts, how can I swap the layouts at runtime?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

So I am going to have a Fragment with 3 layout files.
All 3 Layout files have one textview and 2 buttons.

The first layout file has only the textview and 2 buttons.

The second layout file has only the textview and 3 buttons

The third layout file has only the textview and 4 buttons.

When the fragment is created, I will know which layout file is required and could use a switch statement to choose between them.

My confusion is coming from how to define construct the objects/ui elements.

Since I could return the view in the oncreateView with each layout file no problem.

But how would I only construct the necessary number of buttons?

Since depending on the situation I would only have 2 buttons visible but one class controlling all 4.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need 3 different layouts for this.
Just change the extra buttons visibility depending on your need.

Inflate default layout with textview and 2 buttons and then add your logic.

```
thirdButton.visibility = if(shouldDisplayThirdButton) View.Visible else View.Gone
fourthButton.visibility = if(shouldDisplayFourthButton) View.Visible else View.Gone
```

Comment: The layouts change depending on the buttons though, if I have 2, their need to be side by side.
If I have three they need to be 2 on top and one centered between them and below.
If I have four buttons they are laid out in a cube style.

Answer (score 0):

you can have one layout and just switch buttons visibility based on some conditions:

```
myButton.visibility = View.Visible(or View.Gone)
```

or you can create fragment layout like this:

```
FrameLayout
   LayoutWith2Buttons
   LayoutWith3Buttons
   LayoutWith4Buttons
```

and in fragment switch visibility of those layouts

```
myLayoutWith2Buttons.visibility = View.Visible (or View.Gone)
```

Answer (score 0):

I donot know what you want to get but you can also use ViewPager with PageAdapter

```
class CustomVPAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
private String[] pagesList;
private Context context;


public CustomVPAdapter(Context context, String[] pagesList) {
    this.pagesList= pagesList;
    this.context = context;
   
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.pagesList.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(android.view.View view, Object object) {
    return (view == (ConstraintLayout) object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = ((LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE));
    android.view.View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custome_pager_adapter, container, false);
    final ImageView localImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_page);

   
  
   container.addView(view);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((ConstraintLayout) object);
}
```

}